# Sprite kit game says "May slow down your iPhone"

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, ios10

I'm new with sprite kit. Even I'm using Swift 3 and latest SDKs. Why I'm getting this alert. Sometimes while my app launching on the device. What should I do to overcome this message?

If someone explain it would be great.

[image]

I changed these in build settings, I think that will be enough to go.

Comment: I have never known this to happen, in a game you have built?

Comment: @Scriptable Yes I just started doing something with Sprite Kit. It occurs when I launched.

Comment: Screenshot, PLEASE!!!!!!

Comment: This message is shown when there is no 64bit binary slice in your app, check your build settings.

Comment: oh... @rckoenes, that's much duller than I was hoping.

Comment: If a user launched a 32-bit app, the alert would appear to warn them that the app was not optimized for iOS 10 and its usage may affect overall system performance. Check out http://www.redmondpie.com/ios-alert-may-slow-down-your-iphone-is-back-with-10.1-for-32-bit-apps/

Comment: @rckoenes I changed something in build settings. Updated my question. I think that It will solve.

Comment: @Confused Sorry this alert message not displaying always. Rarely pops up. So there is no screenshot.

Comment: @Amanpreet Thanks but I already checked it, I have asked what should I do to overcome here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is now happening when you launch a 32 bit app on a 64 bit iOS device.

### Why does my 32 bit app slow down a 64 bit iPhone?

When Apple released iOS 7 (the first 64 bit version of iOS) it provided 64 bit versions of the iOS frameworks.

So on a 64 bit iPhone:

- when you run a 32 bit app, the 32 bit versions of the frameworks are loaded in memory
- when you run a 64 bit app, the 64 bit versions are loaded.

This means that if you only run 64 bit app, your memory will be filled with only 1 version of the iOS libraries. On the other hand if you run 32 and 64 bit apps, iOS will need to load in memory both versions of those library.

And this may slow down the device.

### Solution

Just add 64 bit support.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation.